# Filtering AngularJS inside the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, filter

I'm trying to apply some sort of filter to my code but it's not changing anything when i click on the menu. I need to show all my albums initially and if the user clicks in one of te artists i want to filter them. Down here is my controller:

```
Function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'json/json_price_1.json'
}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.artists = data.artists; // response data

    $scope.albums = [];
    $scope.currentArtist = null;
    $scope.setArtist = function(name) {
        $scope.currentArtist = $scope.artists[name];
    };
    if ($scope.currentArtist == null) {
        angular.forEach($scope.artists, function(element, index) {
            angular.forEach(element.albums, function(album, index) {
                $scope.albums.push(album);
            });
        });
    } else {
        angular.forEach($scope.currentArtist.albums, function(album, index) {
            $scope.albums.push(album);
        });
    };

});};
```

My html is the following:

```
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">  
<ul class="topcoat-list" ng-repeat="artist in artists">
    <li class="topcoat-list__item">
        <a href="" ng-click="setArtist(artist.name)">
            {{artist.name}}
        </a>
    </li>   
</ul></div>
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="album in albums">
  <li>{{album.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your time guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an expert in angularjs, the problem is you are not filtering the albums after the artist is set.

```
Function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.setArtist = function (name) {
        $scope.currentArtist = $scope.artists[name];
        $scope.filter();
    };

    $scope.filter = function () {
        $scope.albums = [];
        if (!$scope.currentArtist) {
            angular.forEach($scope.artists, function (element, index) {
                angular.forEach(element.albums, function (album, index) {
                    $scope.albums.push(album);
                });
            });
        } else {
            angular.forEach($scope.currentArtist.albums, function (album, index) {
                $scope.albums.push(album);
            });
        };

    }


    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'json/json_price_1.json'
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.artists = data.artists; // response data

        $scope.currentArtist = undefined;
        $scope.filter()

    });
};
```

The angular solution will be is to use an [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) - something like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a6YBy/3/)